# How to make a round corner inside?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender, and I wanted that the face is smooth and round like the blue line.

[image]

Comment: The same way you did on the top. **Edges are always straight**, so you need more of them to describe curved shapes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add an edge in the center of where the curve should be with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Transform this new edge toward the inside of the object (using *normal [transform orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html?#transform-orientations)* is useful here)
3. [Bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html#bevel-edges) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> with clamp overlap (press <kbd>C</kbd> while using bevel) enabled.

See below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way for example:

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add a loop cut so the line you highlighted in yellow is divided in half.  Move the new cut towards the middle of the blue line you drew, then bevel it to make it smooth.